# Nothing inside ReactDOM.render is loading on iPhone, but it works in the Xcode simulator

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, firebase, redux

I got a full app tested and working locally. I am using React and Redux with Firebase. Deployed to domain and everything was working perfectly. I tried it in Xcode emulator for iPhone. No problem. But when I got a real iphone, it loaded a blank page with the body CSS as far is it could go.

I eliminated the possibility that it was anything in the app itself, because basically nothing inside ReactDOM.render(XXXXX) renders at all.

It works on my android chrome browser fine, it's just iPhone Chrome and Safari. I'm sure other devices may have the same issue. What am I missing with ReactDOM.render?

Here is the Index.HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>Title</title>
   </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="portal"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the index.js

```
import styles2 from "./css/home.css";
import "core-js/es/map";
import "core-js/es/set";
import "raf/polyfill";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import fbConfig from "./config/fire";


const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, {
      userProfile: "users",
      useFirestoreForProfile: true,
      attachAuthIsReady: true
    }),
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig) // redux bindings for firestore
  )
);

//store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then(() => {
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
//registerServiceWorker();
//});
```

Comment: Is anything "interactable" on the physical device, i.e. can you long press to highlight text, copy/paste, etc? Have you tried other iOS devices.  We've had this happen to our mobile app on random iOS devices and it turns out the most successful solution for us is to use a css rule to trick the browser into using hardware acceleration.  Basically do an empty 3d transform `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` on any components that are rendering all white/transparent.  The trouble is finding the problem component.  We stripped down our DOM until it rendered and slowly added stuff back until it broke.

Comment: What can you see when you connect a debugger through safari on the affected connected device?  Can you explore the DOM?  See components highlight as you mouse over them in the inspector tool?